# Deviance loss scores on the training data don't match clf.train_score_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, loss, model-fitting

*TL;DR*: I'm trying to understand the meaning of the `train_score_` attribute of a [`GradientBoostingClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html), and specifically why it doesn't match my following attempt to calculate it directly:

```
my_train_scores = [clf.loss_(y_train, y_pred) for y_pred in clf.staged_predict(X_train)]
```

---

*More details*: I'm interested in the loss scores for both the test and the train data during the different fit stages of the classifier. [I can](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html) use [`staged_predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.staged_predict) and `loss_` to calculate the loss scores for the *test* data:

```
test_scores = [clf.loss_(y_test, y_pred) for y_pred in clf.staged_predict(X_test)]
```

I'm okay with that. My problem is with the *train* loss scores. The documentation suggests to use **`clf.train_score_`**:

> The i-th score train_score_[i] is the deviance (= loss) of the model
>   at iteration i on the in-bag sample. If subsample == 1 this is the
>   deviance on the training data.

yet these `clf.train_score_` values *do not match* my attempt to calculate them directly in `my_train_scores` above. What am I missing here?

---

*The code* I used:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
X, y = make_hastie_10_2()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=5, loss='deviance')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

test_scores = [clf.loss_(y_test, y_pred) for y_pred in clf.staged_predict(X_test)]
print test_scores
print clf.train_score_
my_train_scores = [clf.loss_(y_train, y_pred) for y_pred in clf.staged_predict(X_train)]
print my_train_scores, '<= NOT the same values as in the previous line. Why?'
```

Producing e.g. this output...

```
[0.71319004170311229, 0.74985670836977902, 0.79319004170311214, 0.55385670836977885, 0.32652337503644546]
[ 1.369166    1.35366377  1.33780865  1.32352935  1.30866325]
[0.65541226392533436, 0.67430115281422309, 0.70807893059200089, 0.51096781948088987, 0.3078567083697788] <= NOT the same values as in the previous line. Why?
```

...where the last two rows do not match.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `self.train_score_` is recreated in the following way:

```
test_dev = []
for i, pred in enumerate(clf.staged_decision_function(X_test)):
    test_dev.append(clf.loss_(y_test, pred))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(np.arange(clf.n_estimators) + 1, test_dev, color='#d7191c', label='Test', linewidth=2, alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(np.arange(clf.n_estimators) + 1, clf.train_score_, color='#2c7bb6',    label='Train', linewidth=2, alpha=0.7, linestyle='--')
ax.set_xlabel('n_estimators')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

See the result below. Note that the curves are on top of each other as the training and test data are the same data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question was: Why is `clf.train_score_` not the same as my recreated scores?

Comment: Does this explain the difference you are seeing? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329857/what-is-the-difference-between-decision-function-predict-proba-and-predict-fun

Comment: No, thanks Kevin. My question is particular to GradientBoostingClassifier.